# How do I purchase a product with a one-time price through the Stripe API?

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a product in Stripe with multiple prices, some recurring and a one-time price. (eg. $10/month, $100/year, $1,000 one-time)

For the recurring prices I use `stripe.subscriptions.create` with the `customer`, `items`, etc. as described in the [docs here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create). **But I get an error if I try to list the *one-time* price in the `items` array.**

What is the correct way to handle a one-time price? Do I need to load the price, check if `price.recurring` isn't set, and use a payment intent instead? This seems odd as it doesn't reference the product at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Subscriptions API is designed for collecting recurring payments from customers, and that's why it would err if you specified a one-time price in the `items` array.

Yes, you should check the [type](https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/object#price_object-type) of the price before deciding whether to use Subscriptions API or PaymentIntents API.

Comment: Yeah. That's what I ended up doing. But is a PaymentIntent the right option?

Comment: It seems odd to have an arbitrary payment with no links to the product, coupons, etc, that were used to get to it.

Comment: Or you can use Invoices API for one-time payment, which allows you to specify the price/product, as well as coupon.